# Fifo buffer that alow null elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, fifo

I have a device that comunicate with the program via rs232.Device send a message and  the program read a byte by byte and put in the buffer so another thread parse the buffer.
Problem is that in the message i will have a 0x00 byte {null element for fifo buffer} so i can`t enter that element in the fifo.How to solve that problem.
I use

```
BlockingQueue<Byte> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
```

For entering byte in the fifo:

```
public void serialEvent(jssc.SerialPortEvent event) {
  if (event.isRXCHAR()) {//If data is available
     try {
        buffer = serialPort.readBytes();
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(buffer) + " event");
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        queue.add(buffer[i]);
        }
  } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

And for poll the element

```
byte stx = queue.poll();
```

How to enter null elements because message will have a null bytes?

the code for parsing(thread for parsing):

```
public void run() {
            while (true) {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(queue.size() + " 1 proverka");
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    byte stx = queue.poll();
                    System.out.println(byteToHex(stx) + " parser");
                    if (stx == 0x02) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", stx));
                        System.out.println(queue.size() + " 2 proverka");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            System.out.println(queue.size() + " 3 proverka " + i + " krug");
                            len[i] = queue.poll();
                            System.out.println(byteToHex(len[i]) + " parser");
```

output:

02 event
0000 event
01 event
4 1 proverka
77 event
2 parser
03 event
75 event
6 2 proverka
6 3 proverka 0 krug
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.moduli.ingenico_card_reader.Ingenico_Card_Reader$SerialParser.run(Ingenico_Card_Reader.java:127)

edited with my custom byte class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package es.moduli.ingenico_card_reader;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

/**
 *
 * @author GiGo
 */
public class Ingenico_Card_Reader {

    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static BlockingQueue<CustomByte> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public void open() {
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open port
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params
            int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR;//Prepare mask
            serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
            serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortEvent());//Add SerialPortEventListener
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        SerialParser parser = new SerialParser();
        parser.start();
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static String byteToHex(byte b) {
        int i = b & 0xFF;
        return Integer.toHexString(i);
    }

    public static int byteToIntBE(byte[] b) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        int result = bb.getInt();
        return result;
    }

    public static void sleep(long i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static String hexString(byte[] b) {
        StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(b.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            char hi = Character.forDigit(b[i] >> 4 & 0xF, 16);
            char lo = Character.forDigit(b[i] & 0xF, 16);
            d.append(Character.toUpperCase(hi));
            d.append(Character.toUpperCase(lo));
        }
        return d.toString();
    }

    public static class SerialPortEvent implements SerialPortEventListener {

        byte buffer[];

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(jssc.SerialPortEvent event) {
            if (event.isRXCHAR()) {//If data is available
                //if (event.getEventValue() == 1) {//Check bytes count in the input buffer
                //Read data, if 1 byte available 
                try {
                    buffer = serialPort.readBytes();
                    System.out.println(bytesToHex(buffer) + " event");
                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                        queue.add(new CustomByte(buffer[i], true));
                    }
                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
            // }

        }
    }

    public static class SerialParser extends Thread {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Byte len[];
        int len_mess = 0;
        Byte mess[];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(queue.size() + " 1 proverka");
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    byte stx = queue.poll().getBufferByte();
                    System.out.println(byteToHex(stx) + " parser");
                    if (stx == 0x02) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", stx));
                        System.out.println(queue.size() + " 2 proverka");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            System.out.println(queue.size() + " 3 proverka " + i + " krug");
                            len[i] = queue.poll().getBufferByte();
                            System.out.println(byteToHex(len[i]) + " parser");
                            //sb.append(String.format("%02X ", len[i]));
                        }
                        len_mess = (256 * 256 * len[0]) + (256 * len[1]) + (len[2]);
                        for (int i = 0; i < len_mess; i++) {
                            mess[i] = queue.poll().getBufferByte();
                            System.out.println(byteToHex(mess[i]) + "parser");
                            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", mess[i]));
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(50);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        byte etx = queue.poll().getBufferByte();
                        System.out.println(byteToHex(etx) + "parser");
                        if (etx == 0x03) {
                            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", etx));
                            System.out.println(sb.toString());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("NOT ETX");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("NOT STX");
                    }
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

THE SAME ERROR

02 event
0000017703 event
6 1 proverka
2 parser
75 event
6 2 proverka
6 3 proverka 0 krug
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.moduli.ingenico_card_reader.Ingenico_Card_Reader$SerialParser.run(Ingenico_Card_Reader.java:129)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you can't add a `null` element to `queue` ?

Comment: i add and i check the size of queue is 2 but when i poll the element i get Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @GligorShijakovski: That's because your `stx` variable is of type `byte` rather than `Byte`, so it's auto-unboxing. (Having said that, it's not clear why you don't just keep byte 0 in its existing form...)

Comment: Why don't you add the `0x00` byte as `(byte) 0` ?

Answer (score 3):

A `BlockingQueue<Byte>` can have `(byte) 0x00` values however it is very inefficient way to deal with a stream of bytes.  This will create around 16 bytes of garbage for each actual byte sent.

Another approach is to use a Pipe stream which is designed for this sort of task.

```
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
```

In the thread reading from the RS232, you can write the bytes you read to the `out` and in another thread you can process this by reading from `in`.

This approach doesn't create any garbage on a per byte basis.

Comment: If the `Byte` objects are obtained using `Byte.valueOf(byte)`, no garbage is generated.  The `Byte` class caches `Byte` objects for all 256 possible `byte` values.

Comment: how to parse the byte in the best way?message is in format stx | len | message | etx | crc

Comment: @GligorShijakovski I would try reading the data progressively.

Answer (score 0):

Your can wrap the `Byte` class with your custom Byte class:

```
public class CustomByte {
    private Byte bufferByte;
    private boolean isNull;

    // Add constructor, getters/setters as required
}
```

and change the queue type to use this type.
Then when you encounter a `null` byte just add a `CustomByte` object with the flag on:

```
queue.add(new CustomByte(buffer[i], true))
```

then when polling `CustomByte` objects you can query the `isNull` flag

Comment: This is unnecessary.  There is not problem with representing `0x00` as a `Byte`. It ain't `null` in the Java sense.

Comment: Yeah, and Lawrey's answer seems much more efficient anyway.

Comment: I write a custombyte class as you tell but the same i get a Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: As others suggested have you tried adding (byte)0 to the queue when encountering 0x00 ?